# MvcBuildViews ASPNETCOMPILER error ASPRUNTIME: Failed to map the path '/temp'

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

My web project builds and works fine under Visual Studio 2017, but I'm having trouble creating a project in TeamCity.

MSBuild Error "ASPNETCOMPILER error ASPRUNTIME: Failed to map the path '/temp'" occured.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this problem in the TeamCity build, I use the MSBUILD builder like this:

Targets: Rebuild;Publish

Command line parameters for build and tests: /p:WebProjectOutputDir="%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\Website"
You can then use the Website directory as your artifact.